# execute python script with argparse inside python script

Tags: python, argparse, execfile

I got two different python script, the first one is using argparse to get some additional argument (I will call it arg.py) and the second one is my main script (main.py).
I want to call arg.py inside main.py but I don't know how to do so. I take a look at the command execfile but I didn't manage to make it work.
I try to put
`execfile('arg.py -h')`
In main.py but python try to find the file 'arg.py -h' which doesn't exist. Does anyone know how to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you enter the complete path to `arg.py` as argument in `execfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it as a separate process using `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen`.  If you don't want to run it as a child process, then it starts to get more complicated (depending on the structure of your `arg.py` script.

`execfile` takes the file you pass to it and includes it in the current script -- Much like a `#include` pre-processor directive in c/c++ (although this is done dynamically).  One really ugly option using `execfile` would be:

```
#completely untested.
import sys
def run_script(script_name,*args):
    _argv = sys.argv[:]
    sys.argv = list(args)
    execfile(script_name)
    sys.argv = _argv
```